# fixed height (table) with rows that overflow going on a second column

Tags: html, css

Probably this is not possible ? I have a table with 3 columns like this 
https://jsfiddle.net/ryvL02de/ 
I would like for rows overflowing the height to go on a second column on the right side instead.

Most likely this is possible with divs though ? Not really set on a table solutions
[image]

```
    <tr>
             <td>B-111-aaa</td>
             <td>08:00</td>
             <td>Firstname Lastname</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>B-111-aaa</td>
            <td>08:15</td>
            <td>Firstname Lastname</td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: Using `column-count` could get you some of the way there. Though I'm not sure how you would handle the table header: https://jsfiddle.net/gvd5L1wk/

Comment: You'd need to use JS

Comment: Oh that's great column-count is what I was looking for :) Learned something new thanks! I don't need the header because I will show all the data in one table without grouping it. Something like what the airport terminals show.

Answer (score 1):

```
CSS : class - space.{white-space:pre-line}
<tr>
   <td class="space">B-111-aaa</td>
   <td>08:00</td>
   <td>Firstname Lastname</td>
   </tr>
<tr>
   <td class="space">B-111-aaa</td>
   <td>08:15</td>
   <td>Firstname Lastname</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: When answering, please clarify why this answer is the right solution

Answer (score 0):

Your question looks like confusing one.
If you are looking for, column data should not display overflowing to next column. 
then you can use style property for column as `style='min-width:100px'` So data automatically displayed in readable format to user under appropriate columns.

More cleaner code can be,

`

```
<style>
.fixed-width-Column{
   min-width:100px;
   text-align:left;
}
</style>
```

`

Your HTML:

`

```
<tr><th class="fixed-width-Column">NrAuto</th>
<th class="fixed-width-Column">Ora</th>
<th class="fixed-width-Column">Resp</th>
</tr>
```

`